# Get Creation Time of an AWS Batch job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

When executing an AWS Batch job, I would like to know when the job was created. The API [provides a way](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_JobDetail.html) to get job details, including `createdAt`. But how do I know the job id to fetch those details?

Answer (score 1):

A list of job IDs on which this job depends. A job can depend upon a maximum of 20 jobs. The job ID of the AWS Batch job associated with this dependency.

Use following link might help,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_JobDependency.html